# How to Change Time In PM Or AM in 24 Hour format

Tags: c#

how to Change Time According to PM OR AM please help me this in C#

```
string time = "0610";    OR "1200" OR "0100"  OR "1430"
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(time);
```

i Need like this :  06:10 AM

Comment: You can output a `DateTime` anyway you want using `ToString` and a format, either standard or custom. Internally, a `DateTime` isn't stored as a string in any format, it is a binary structure representing the date+time.

Comment: Where are you displaying the parsed DateTime as a string again?

Comment: Read the documentation for `DateTime.ToString`.

Comment: We don't understand what you are trying to do; where are you getting these strings from and [what are you going to do with them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52392583/edit) your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ParseExact` to parse the string into a date/time:

```
string time = "0610";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HHmm"", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
// HH means 24-hour format with leading zero
```

Note that `DateTime` does not HAVE a format, it just represents a point in time. If you then want to *display* it with the AM/PM indicator, you could use `ToString`, or set the format specifier in the display control (if applicable):

```
string timeAmPm = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: @D Stanley  thanks for anwer but its show me error No overload for method 'ParseExact' takes 2 arguments

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
//date is your datetime
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

string formatTime =  date.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(formatTime);
```

See more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ttSpecifier